# What is happening to a domain with status PENDING DELETE as well as AUTORENEWPERIOD?

Tags: domain-registration

A domain I once registered but gave away:

```
Expiration Date:13-Mar-2013 14:39:45 UTC
Sponsoring Registrar:Directi Internet Solutions Pvt. Ltd. dba PublicDomainRegistry.com 
(R159-LRMS)
Status:PENDING DELETE RESTORABLE
Status:HOLD
Status:AUTORENEWPERIOD
Status:REDEMPTIONPERIOD
Registrant ID:DI_7838158
Registrant Name:scherhag
Registrant Organization:Locafroid europe sa
```

I'd like to get this domain back and I'm hoping that PENDING DELETE means it might soon be released to the market. However I'm not sure, as there is also a status that says AUTORENEWPERIOD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](http://homepageuniverse.com/support/knowledgebase/question.php?qstId=71) and [here](http://www.dotweekly.com/do-not-transfer-a-domain-during-auto-renew-period/)

> A domain with status: REDEMPTIONPERIOD (or PENDING DELETE RESTORABLE
>   for .info domains) has expired and was not properly renewed for at
>   least 40 days.
>
> Domains which are not renewed are deleted, after which point the
>   Registry will hold the domain in the REDEMPTIONPERIOD/PENDING DELETE
>   RESTORABLE for 30 days.

and

> If your domain happened to hit the expiry date and you remembered a
>   day later and quickly renewed the domain, it’s still considered to be
>   in Auto Renew Period.